# Laravel Voyager: only see a menu item if the user is admin

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, roles, voyager

I'm using Voyager, and I would like to solve, if the user is admin, see one more menu item in the welcome page.

Thank you in advance for the answers!

```
<body>
  <div class="flex-center position-ref full-height">
    @if (Route::has('login'))
      <div class="top-right links">
        @auth
          <a href="{{ url('/home') }}">Home</a>
        @else
          <a href="{{ route('login') }}">Login</a>
          <a href="{{ route('register') }}">Register</a>
        @endauth
      </div>
    @endif

    <div class="content">
      <div class="title m-b-md">
        Laravel
      </div>

      <div class="links">
        <a href="https://laravel.com/docs">Documentation</a>
        <a href="https://laracasts.com">Laracasts</a>
        <a href="https://laravel-news.com">News</a>
        <a href="https://forge.laravel.com">Forge</a>
        <a href="https://github.com/laravel/laravel">GitHub</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: How are you building up your menu? Show us the relevant controller's methods and views.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can check for the role of the authenticated user inside your view. Maybe something like this:

```
@if (Auth::user()->hasRole('admin'))
    <a href="...">This can only be seen by admins</a>
@endif
```

Comment: Thank you my friend. I was stuck for 2 weeks ahahhah

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily from the control pannel
Go to the corresponding role(s) and remove the permission for that model, and it will be removed from the menu for that user
For example: if you want to hide Media from the menu for a perticular role or every role, go to that role and uncheck "Browse media".

Answer (score 0):

- You can simply login to the dashboard
- Click on the edit button for that particular role
- check and uncheck what you want that role permission

visit [Voyager Academy Roles Permisson](https://voyager.devdojo.com/academy/roles-permissions/) for more information